# Can a creature with Telepathy communicate when it is under the effect of Hold Monster?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, telepathy

My psuedodragon familiar is currently under the effect of [Hold Monster](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/hold-monster/). Hold monster specifically restricts "speech", but I think that means words that come out of a moving mouth.

Is that right? Can it communicate using its [telepathy](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Telepathy-Su-)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### A *held monster* can use [telepathy](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Telepathy-Su-).

Per the spell ***[hold person](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/hold-person)*** (referenced in ***hold monster***, the Condition imparted is [paralysis](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Paralyzed).

> A paralyzed character is frozen in place and unable to move or act. A paralyzed character has effective Dexterity and Strength scores of 0 and is helpless, **but can take purely mental actions.** A winged creature flying in the air at the time that it becomes paralyzed cannot flap its wings and falls. A paralyzed swimmer can’t swim and may drown. A creature can move through a space occupied by a paralyzed creature—ally or not. Each square occupied by a paralyzed creature, however, counts as 2 squares to move through.